# UIButton Animation Stops When Returning to App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cabasicanimation

I'm calling the following method in my menuViewController's viewDidLoad & viewDidAppear, to give my button a pulsing effect, when the app loads my main view.

```
-(void) pulseButton {
CABasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
pulseAnimation.duration = .5;
pulseAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1];
pulseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
[menuButton.layer addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:nil];
}
```

When I first load the app it pulses perfectly. Why does it stop animating when I leave the app and return immediately?

### UPDATE

I added an NSLog to my viewDidAppear method and I realize it is not getting called. The view I'm displaying is a subview that I added in the viewDidLoad of my main controller the following way:

```
MenuViewController *MVC = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:MVC.view];
[self addChildViewController:MVC];
[MVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Could that be the problem as to why viewDidAppear is not being called, hence my method isn't being called?

Comment: You want to open the new View in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi I want to call the pulseButton method in the viewDidAppear method of my new view.

Answer (score 1):

You cam simply use `NSNotificationCenter` to achieve this

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //YOUR_STUFF

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(pulseButton)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];

}
```

** *CALayer animation automatically removes when View is not visible*

Comment: thats not what he wants...he he calling pulseButton method in vieDidAppear which gets called when he resumes the app..so no need of notification...

Comment: As I understand, he is saying that when he leaves the app and return to the app again (like pressing the home button), the animation stops

Comment: And who says that `viewDidLoad` runs on resume. It pnly runs in first time the app begins

Comment: I didn't say viwDidLoad...I said viwDidAppear..please read again dude..and it gets called everytime when u resume the app..

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Thanks for your answer, but the way I'm calling my method works just fine right now, which is why your answer isn't useful. The problem is that it stops animating when returning to the app (nothing to do with viewDidLoad).

Comment: CALayer animation automatically removes when `View` is not visible

Comment: @user1886754 so what did you want?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a view as a sub view will not call its didAppear method. You should do the stuff in viewDidLoad either.